# Postgres. Перегенерить ID и sequence

Tags: postgresql

Всем привет, возникла весьма нетривиальная задача. Есть большая таблица с данными, из нее постоянно данные "уезжают" в другие места безвозвратно,                        внешних ключей на ID этой таблицы нет, однако в этом процессе постгресовский авто-инкремент (он же sequence) продолжает накручиваться и сейчас у меня integer out of range, а в таблице всего несколько миллионов записей.
Собственно вопрос, как в постгресе пересобрать ID и sequence таблицы? Т.е., грубо говоря, чтобы все текущие записи заимели ID от 1-го и до count(записей)?

Спасибо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Вариант первый

выкинуть sequence вообще и использовать первичный ключ из предметной области.

### Вариант второй

Чтобы быстро оживить проект: перезапустить сиквенс заново.

```
ALTER SEQUENCE sequence_name RESTART WITH 1;
```

Поскольку он вам судя по вопросу объективно не нужен вообще. И можно попросить сиквенс самостоятельно ходить по кругу:

```
alter sequence seqtest_i_seq maxvalue 2147483647 cycle;
```

### Вариант третий

Изменить тип поля на 64-битный `bigint`. За время существования приложения вы его не исчерпаете.

### Вариант четвёртый

О котором спрашиваете вы - перенумеровать всю таблицу и проставить текущее значение сиквенсу в максимальное число из существующих. Но зачем? Операция неуклюжая, повторять каждые 2 млрд строк. Ну если очень хочется, [то как-то так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29747683):

```
UPDATE thetable SET rowid=col_serial FROM 
(SELECT rowid, row_number() OVER ( ORDER BY lngid) AS col_serial FROM thetable ORDER BY lngid) AS t1 
WHERE thetable.rowid=t1.rowid;

select setval(seqtest_i_seq, max(rowid) + 1) from thetable;
```

Comment: На сколько я представлял, секвенс - отдельная от таблицы сущность и если он будет ходить по кругу то по логике он может выдать значание, повторяющее id существующей записи. Или в postgresql эта проблема как то решена и он будет перескакивать существующие id ?

Comment: @Mike будет конечно значения повторяться и провоцировать ошибку unique constraint. Поэтому дефолтно они no cycle Но это если будут повторяться, по описанию автора похоже, что эта транзитная табличка и данные в ней не задерживаются на время замыкания int32. Универсальный вариант подходящий всем - третий. Правильный с точки зрения теории РСУБД - первый.

Comment: @Мелкий спасибо за развернутый ответ. Первый вариант не подходит, слишком много переделывать придется в системах, которые эту табличку используют и завязаны на этом ID. Второй тоже, так как таблица не только транзитную функцию несет и консистентность первичного ключа важна. Поэтому выбрал для себя третий вариант, только вот теперь наверное придется пересоздавать таблицу, ALTER COLUMN на 2млрд записей никогда не выполнится...

Comment: Так вы же писали, что всего 2млн значений, а не млрд? :) Зависит от дисков и общего объёма (включая индексы!) в общем-то, хотя бы один раз таблицу полностью переписать придётся в любом случае.